# How to remove first pixel row from jquery navbar?

Tags: jquery, css, jquery-mobile

There's a bright pixel row (some kind of reflection or so) through all items at the top end of the jquery mobile navbar.

[Sample](http://forum.jquery.com/viewImage.do?fileId=14737000002113623&forumGroupId=14737000000003003)

Which `CSS` properties need to be overwritten to remove this row of highlighted pixels at the head of the navbar (ui-btn-inner I think)?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Override this rule on jquery.mobile-1.2.0.css:732.

```
.ui-btn-inner {
    border-top: 1px solid white;
    border-color: rgba(255, 255, 255, .3);
}
```

So something like:

```
.ui-btn-inner {
    border-top: none;
}
```